# Add mat-datepicker on mat-input conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I would like to add a material date picker conditionally but **without duplicating my input tag**.

For example, if i have this :

.ts :

```js
isDatePickerInputList: boolean[] = [false, true]
```

The easy way would be to have 2 input in a *ngFor : the first input would be a normal input and the second one an input linked with a matDatePicker

But **i don't want this solution** because it would mean duplicating my input tag

.html :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let isDatePickerInput of isDatePickerInputList">

   <ng-container *ngIf="isDatePickerInput">
      <input [matDatepicker]="picker" matInput>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container *ngIf="!isDatePickerInput">
      <input matInput>
   </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

I want something like that (but of course that is not working actually) :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let isDatePickerInput of isDatePickerInputList">

   <input [matDatepicker]="isDatePickerInput ? 'picker' : ''" matInput>
   <ng-container *ngIf="isDatePickerInput">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you maybe share what the actual problem is with the 2 inputs switched with `ngIf`?

Comment: i have a generic form and i have a lot of parameters so i don't want to duplicate my input tag for avoid duplicate my code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let isDatePickerInput of isDatePickerInputList">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isDatePickerInput"> text {{isDatePickerInput!.picker}} 
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Didnt try but sure not working i thought maybe here you find something usefull: [angular template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-non-null-assertion-operator---)

Comment: i need to keep my input